# Unable to publish to npm registry, 401 error

Tags: npm

I am unable to publish my package to npm. I am logged in as a user with correct access to that package.

After logging in, I run this command to show I am logged in:

```
$ npm whoami
ganchrowsci
```

Then I run this command to ensure that the current user has access to the current package:

```
$ npm access ls-collaborators
{
  "ganchrowsci": "read-write"
}
```

And then I run publish and it ends with an error:

```
$ npm publish
...<snip>
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT http://registry.npmjs.com/gs-utils - You must be logged in to publish packages.
```

This is clearly showing that I am not logged in, but that is also clearly not true. I can't understand why I'm not able to publish. Can you explain what I am doing wrong?

Another piece of information is that, this used to work and we have published many versions of this package, but we haven't published recently. It's only this latest change that we're having trouble with.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
npm adduser --registry=https://registry.npmjs.com
```

I needed to explicitly specify the registry, even though that registry specified in my .npmrc:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 11):

I created an account in npm (https://www.npmjs.com/).
Then created a token in that account.

The following command worked for me:

`npm adduser --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<token-from-npm>`